# Gradle ordered sourcesets

Tags: javascript, gradle

I'm using Gradle's concept of SourceSets as a way to declare JavaScript sources, however, I can't quite figure out a way to allow sources to be declared in a given order. What I want is something like:

```
javascript.source {
    custom {
        js {
            srcDir "src/js"
            include "file2.js", "file1.js"
        }
    }
}
```

to give a collection of files in the order I declared.

I know that I can do this with a FileTree, but I feel like there's something I'm missing to make this work with declaring SourceSets.

If this isn't possible, what should I use for ordered sources?

EDIT: Note that I need order-dependence because I'm working with JavaScript.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the name `sourceSet` implies that the sources are unordered. The other catch is that `include` is a pattern filter, so it cannot be used to order items, but only to exclude items that are not in the list.

Comment: I'll buy that the `set` in the name denotes unordered, but I am hoping for some way to have ordered sources, with or without `sourceSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you to try declaring a second `sourceSet` containing `file1.js` and making your original `sourceSet` depend on it. So roughly:

```groovy
javascript.source {
    custom2 {
        js {
            srcDir "src/js2"
            include "file2.js"
        }
    }
    custom {
        js {
            srcDir "src/js"
            include "file1.js"
        }
        compileClasspath += custom2.outputs
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is possible with the plugin that you are using, though. But hope you get the idea.

I guess in a declarative system like Gradle, the only way to specify order is though declaring dependencies between the different parts, and letting Gradle work-out the order for you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping to use AMD or CommonJS to declare dependencies, but until then I need some way to handle them. I'm gonna call this "as good as I'm going to get". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a `sourceSet` in gradle is a logical grouping for source and resource files. (No ordering implied)

For the Java plugin, for example, this means that when gradle tries to compile your app, it knows where to find the source files for the compilation process.

I am unsure exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Are you using any special plugins here? Why do you need the special order of the files? Please explain the big picture of what you are trying to do. I am pretty sure that `sourceSet` will not help you here.

Comment: I'm attempting to use `SourceSets` with JavaScript files that are order-dependent. It's likely that you're right in that there is no solution with sourceSets other than adding their files Collections together when using them in tasks. Are there any other options?

Comment: @EricWendelin: I don't know much about javascript. Why are they order dependent?

Comment: If I am either combining a collection of files or writing their paths out to a file, they must be loaded in a certain order. For example, a jQuery plugin must have jQuery loaded first.